# GDB: how to change a convenience variable from a built-in python

Tags: python, gdb

How do I assign something to a gdb *convenience variable* from its built-in python? I thought it should be simple, because it naturally arises while trying to implement a user-defined function. However I couldn't find anything.

**UPD:** Added a simplified example. My real function is more complex though. Anyway, a way to transfer a variable from python up to gdb would help greatly.

*An example of usage (achtung! — it raises an error):*

```
#accept a string, return it's lenght
define RetLenOfArg
  py arg0 = gdb.parse_and_eval("$arg0")
  set $Retrn = py len(arg0)
end
```

Comment: Please explain your problem in greater detail and with relevant examples/code if possible

Comment: I found a quick startup guide about GDB convenience functions and arguments in here: http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Functions-In-Python.html

Comment: @Ivaylo yes, you're right, you may post it as an answer. To sum up a steps: instead of implementing a function in _.gdbinit_ we need to create a whole class in a separate python file, load it in a gdb through a command `source <python_file>`, and then use. In my real case I will need anyway create one more function that will use a python one. Cumbersome, but that's how it is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> accept a string, return it's lenght

If you indeed need strlen you can use `$_strlen` - a built in gdb convenience function that compute string length:

```
(gdb) set $Retrn=$_strlen("test")
(gdb) p $Retrn
$4 = 4
```

> how to assign something to a GDB convenience variable from a built-in python?

You can use gdb.execute:

```
>more my_own_len.py
class my_own_len (gdb.Function):
   def __init__ (self):
     super (my_own_len, self).__init__ ("my_own_len")

   def invoke (self, arg):
      res=len(arg.string())
      gdb.execute( "set $Retrn=" + str(res))
      return res

my_own_len()
```

This is a test:

```
>gdb -q -x my_own_len.py
(gdb) p $_strlen("test")
$1 = 4
(gdb) p $my_own_len("test")
$2 = 4
(gdb) p $Retrn
$3 = 4
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 5):

There exists gdb's python API to get/set convenience variable: from the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Basic-Python.html)

> Function: **gdb.convenience_variable (name)** Return the value of the
> convenience variable (see Convenience Vars) named name. name must be a
> string. The name should not include the ‘$’ that is used to mark a
> convenience variable in an expression. If the convenience variable
> does not exist, then None is returned.
>
> Function: **gdb.set_convenience_variable (name, value)** Set the value of
> the convenience variable (see Convenience Vars) named name. name must
> be a string. The name should not include the ‘$’ that is used to mark
> a convenience variable in an expression. If value is None, then the
> convenience variable is removed. Otherwise, if value is not a
> gdb.Value (see Values From Inferior), it is is converted using the
> gdb.Value constructor.

Comment: Note: that's a GDB 8.2 feature, in case someone needs it with an older version use `gdb.execute` as mentioned in the accepted answer.